# Solving a simple Function Problem

Tags: functions

If $f(x) + f(2-x)=4$  for all x, ﬁnd $f(y-2) + f(4-y)$? This is not a HW question, however I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Just use the substitution $x=y-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider $x=y-2$.$\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to consider

$$2 - x = y - 2$$

Then it follows that

$$x = 4 - y$$

and hence you have

$$\eqalign{
  & f(x) + f(2 - x) =   \cr 
  & f(4 - y) + f(y - 2) =   \cr 
  & f(y - 2) + f(4 - y) = 4 \cr} $$